# How to get userID and display from firebase (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using firebase with reactJs,
I want to display the username and the id of the user.
I have App.js file that send props to User.js component, to display the data.
For now, I success to display name for each user in list - somthing like that:

Username: James

Username: Jhon
.
.
.

I want to add below the 'Username' the doc id for each user.

My firebase structur:

```
Users-
     -someId1-
             -Name: James
     -someId2-
             -Name: Jhon
```

My map function in App.js to pass data to User.js component:

```
return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {users.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <User
                             name={item.Name}
                        />                          
                    )
                })}</div>
        </div>
);
```

User.js :

```
function User({ name }) {
.
.
.
return (
        <div>
            <p>Username: {name}</p>
        </div>
);
}
```

How can I display also the id (someId1, someId2) like:

Username: James
Id: someId1

Username: Jhon
Id: someId2

Thank you!

Comment: How does `users` look like (e.g. in console log when you print it)? Does it have `id` along with `name`?

Comment: I think you want to show the keys (someId) along with it's value. If so, then there are several ways to do that. You can check `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys() with Object.values()`

Comment: @AjeetShah There is no field that calls 'id'. I can say that I just want to display the id of the document.

Comment: @SifatHaque how can i pass the Object.entries() or Object.keys() to User.js component? For example, I can pass item.name and get it in the component, so how can i get the id?

Comment: @DorCo You can display all the properties available in `users` array. Let's say if `users` looks like: `[{ id: 1, name: 'abc, city: 'xyz''}, { id: 2, name: 'def, city: 'pqr''}, ...so on ]` then you can show `id`, `name` and `city` of each user on UI. If `users` has not enough properties, then you should make changes at backend side so that it returns more properties in `users` array. (PS: I have less idea of firebase).

Comment: it depends on your data. It would be easier if you could share exact data here. @DorCo

Comment: this is users print:
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Name: "James"}
1: {Name: "Jhon"}

for each user there is one field - Name. the id is not really a field, it's the id of the document. the users creates dynamically so the document id create as auto by firebase. i need to get this ids for make some action with user like update, delete and set data. for now i just want to display the ids, and then it will be easy to make the actions.

Comment: I solved it by enter all the ids' to array, and passed it with map function with index for each user. Then in User.js component i got all the user object and the id of the user.

Thank you all for helping!

Comment: Hi @DorCo could you write an answer with your solution please?